# Automating submit50 using bash script

Tags: bash, cs50

So, after having completed a large part of the CS50P course, I noticed that I could submit my assignments via submit50. However it's seriously time consuming (it takes maybe 6 - 8 minutes per submission to connect for me, maybe because I'm not using codespaces) and I have over half a course's worth of submissions, so I thought it would be cool to write a script to automate submissions. I spent half a day writing this tiny script and I really want it to work!!!

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pilks/cs50/python

for d in ./*;
do cd $d && for d2 in ./*;
do cd $d2 && yes yes | submit50 cs50/problems/2022/python/$d2 --log-level info;
cd ..
done
cd ..
done
```

It "works", in that it connects and seems to say 'yes' to the 'are you sure?' question. but then the upload just fails for some unknown reason. Using --log-level info provides this log:

---

```
Connecting...
Authenticating...
Verifying...
(INFO) git clone --bare --single-branch ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/me50/[user].git --branch cs50/problems/2022/python/./einstein
(INFO) git clone --bare --single-branch ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/me50/[user].git
Preparing...
(INFO) git config --bool core.bare false
(INFO) git config --path core.worktree /tmp/tmp7lbn0lum
(INFO) git checkout --force cs50/problems/2022/python/./einstein .gitattributes
(INFO) git config user.email [user]@users.noreply.github.com
(INFO) git config user.name [user]
(INFO) git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/cs50/problems/2022/python/./einstein
(INFO) git add -f einstein.py
Files that will be submitted:
./einstein.py
Keeping in mind the course's policy on academic honesty, are you sure you want to submit these files (yes/no)? Uploading...
(INFO) git commit -m 'automated commit by submit50 [lang=en_GB:en]' --allow-empty
Sorry, something's wrong, please try again. If the problem persists, please 
visit our status page https://cs50.statuspage.io for more information.
Submission cancelled.
Connecting...
```

...and on it goes trying to upload the next file.

It looks like it's failing on the git commit, but in theory my script is doing exactly the same thing as entering the details manually would be, especially in terms of git, which has all been set up in advance to work automatically.

I've done it manually and it works absolutely fine. For reference here's the log when I do it manually and it works:

```
$ submit50 cs50/problems/2022/python/einstein --log-level info
Connecting...
Authenticating...
Verifying...
(INFO) git clone --bare --single-branch ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/me50/pilks7 .git --branch cs50/problems/2022/python/einstein
Preparing...
(INFO) git config --bool core.bare false
(INFO) git config --path core.worktree /tmp/tmpobm69p4d
(INFO) git checkout --force cs50/problems/2022/python/einstein .gitattributes
(INFO) git config user.email pilks7@users.noreply.github.com
(INFO) git config user.name pilks7
(INFO) git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/cs50/problems/2022/python/einstein
(INFO) git add -f einstein.py
Files that will be submitted:
./einstein.py
Keeping in mind the course's policy on academic honesty, are you sure you want to submit these files (yes/no)? yes
Uploading...
(INFO) git commit -m 'automated commit by submit50 [lang=en_GB:en]' --allow-empty
(INFO) git push origin cs50/problems/2022/python/einstein
(INFO) git rev-parse HEAD
Go to https://submit.cs50.io/users/pilks7/cs50/problems/2022/python/einstein to see your results.
```

Could it be possible that the difference between
`cs50/problems/2022/python/einstein`
and
`cs50/problems/2022/python/./einstein`
is causing the issue? After all, it doesn't fail with

```
Invalid slug: cs50/problems/2022/python/./0_funcs_and_vars/einstein/einstein.py.
 Did you mean something else?
Submission cancelled.
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, pretty obvious answer here...

I removed the leading ./ from the ./* in the shell script. It now reads:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pilks/cs50/python

for d in *;
do cd $d && for d2 in *;
do cd $d2 && yes yes | submit50 cs50/problems/2022/python/$d2 --log-level info;
cd ..
done
cd ..
done
```

and appears (hopefully) to be working properly now.

Comment: The problem then is that it will not work for directories which start with a dash. Perhaps a more robust solution would be to keep the `./` but remove it with a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) where required. But of course, that's a rather specific corner case, so maybe just document this restriction if you want to share the script.